# Which is More Important in iOS: Memory or CPU?

Tags: ios, performance

I have been testing several different extensions for viewing animated GIFs in iOS.  Here are my (non-scientific) results:

```
Extension           CPU    Memory
Animated-Gif-iOS    6%     26.3 MB  (caches downloaded data)
FLAnimatedImage     5%     32.3 MB
Gifu                0%     174.8 MB
SwiftGif            0%     174.4 MB
YLGIFImage          6%     32.2 MB
iOSDevCenters+GIF   0%     173.7 MB
```

What is the preference for trading memory usage for CPU usage?  Should this decision change if I plan on showing multiple animated GIFs on the screen at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you find most important. Higher RAM will give you better **prowess to run multiple things together**. Higher processing speed gives you **faster results**.

Read [this](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-more-important-in-a-smartphone-the-RAM-or-the-processor-1#!n=18) guide that explain the difference further.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems with multiple images, higher RAM *might* be better, but testing should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Higher RAM will let you run more multiple things together. Higher processing will give you faster results. Yes it would change to run multiple GIFs. The problem is GIFs need both. Its mostly your choice for want you want. Hope I helped!